# Python tkinter theme on mac

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am having a problem with themed widgets using tkinter. The code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.config(background = "blue")
ttk.Button(root, text="ttk").pack()
ttk.Entry(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is on Mac, themed widgets have a grey border around them as shown in the screenshot below.

My question is, is it possible make the border/background of the themed widgets transparent or match background color of the parent container?

[image: Mac]

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer is yes.  The idea of themed widgets is that you can define a customized theme or style and use that with multiple widgets.  What I know about actually doing that comes from a first reading of chapters 46 to 50 of http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html